# Combine return request response with different format

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, combine

Hei, I have a SwiftUI with its viewModel. When the user taps on the Login button I run the `viewModel.registerAccount` function.

```
func registerAccount() {
    authService.registerAccount(params: params)
        .sink { (dataResponse) in
            if let error = dataResponse.error {
                //
            } else {
                //
            }
        }.store(in: &cancellableSet)
}
```

In this function I make a call to my `AuthService` where I want to save some values and change the response.

```
class AuthService {
    private let apiClient: APIClient = APIClient()
    private var guid: String?

    func registerAccount(params: [String: Any]) -> AnyPublisher<DataResponse<RegisterAccountResponse, Error>, Never> {
        let registerRequest = RegisterAccountRequest(params: params) // (url + method + params + ...)
        let apiRequest = apiClient.request(request: registerRequest)
        // i would like to read response, save guid
        // change response type and return only Error?
        return apiRequest
    }
}
```

Also the `APIClient` definition.

```
class APIClient {
    private let session: Session = Session(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    func request<T: APIRequest>(request: T) -> AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T.Response, Error>, Never> {
        request
            .dataRequest(session: session)
            .publishDecodable(type: T.Response.self)
            .map { response in
                response.mapError { error in
                    return error
                }
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

But this doesn't solve my needs. What would I like is to know if there is a way to read the response in `AuthService`, and return a response of type `Error?`.

At one point I had this in mind, to listed also in `AuthService` but I want to change the response and send only an object of format `Error?`.

```
func registerAccount(params: [String: Any]) -> 
AnyPublisher<DataResponse<RegisterAccountResponse, Error>, Never> {
    let registerRequest = RegisterAccountRequest(params: params)
    let apiRequest = apiClient.request(request: registerRequest)
        
    apiRequest.sink { dataResponse in
        if let guid = dataResponse.value?.guidFlow {
            self.guid = guid
        }
    }.store(in: &cancellableSet)
        
    return apiRequest
}
```

I also thought at this, but I was looking for a more Combine/SwiftUI approach.

```
func registerAccount(params: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let registerRequest = RegisterAccountRequest(params: params)
    let apiRequest = apiClient.request(request: registerRequest)
    
    apiRequest.sink { dataResponse in
        if let value = dataResponse.value {
            // save guid and return nill or backend error (format Error)
        } else {
            completion(dataResponse.error)
        }
    }.store(in: &cancellableSet)
}
```

Comment: Do you just need to return` AnyPublisher<Void, Error>`?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I find odd is that your `APIClient.request` appears to be returning an `AnyPublisher<DataResponse<RegisterAccountResponse, Error>, Never>`.  I would expect it to return a `AnyPublisher<RegisterAccountResponse, Error>` -- a stream that either reports a response or an error.

If you have the ability to change the `APIClient` I'd change that.  If you don't have control over that code, we can work around it with `tryMap`.

It really seems that you want `registerAccount` on `AuthService` to return a publisher that either emits a single GUID, or an error.  That might look like this:

```
class AuthService {
    private let apiClient = APIClient()

    func registerAccount(params: [String: Any]) -> AnyPublisher<UUID?, Error> {
        let registerRequest = RegisterAccountRequest(params: params)

        return apiClient.request(request: registerRequest)
            .tryMap { (response: DataResponse<RegisterAccountResponse, Error>) throws -> UUID? in
                switch response {
                    case .success(let registerAccountResponse) :
                        return registerAccountResponse.value?.guidFlow
                    case .failure(let error) :
                        throw error
                }
            }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: `func request<T: APIRequest>(request: T) -> AnyPublisher<T.Response, Error> {
        session.request(request.url,
                        method: request.httpMethod,
                        ...)
            .publishDecodable(type: T.Response.self)
            .map { response in
                response.mapError { error in
                    return error
                }
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }`

Comment: I tried changing the method APIClient method but I get `Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<T.Response, DataResponsePublisher<T.Response>.Failure>' (aka 'AnyPublisher<T.Response, Never>') to return type 'AnyPublisher<T.Response, Error>'`. Maybe you can help me downcast it from that DataRequest type to the response type you mentioned.

Comment: I don't know what type `publishDecodable` is returning.  Google suggests it might have something to do with Alamofire? If so, and if the doocumentation aligns with your code, then I would take the `map` operation out of your `APIClient`.  Just let it return a `DataResponse<T.Response, Error>`... though from the type signatures, it looks like your `RegisterAccountResponse` Failure subtype is `Never` which implies that response can never fail.  I'm afraid the deeper we get into your particular type, and the libraries you rely on, the less help I'll be.